# Can i use projector inside an aggregate root

Tags: event-sourcing

Is it okay to use a Projection inside an AggregateRoot? A typical case would be using ProductInventoryProjection inside OrderAggregateRoot when placing an order. Is it anti pattern?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it okay to use a Projection inside an AggregateRoot?

That's pretty common; trying to support query directly from an event history can be pretty clumsy.  So it is common to pre-compute answers and cache them separately - designing a projection function to do that is generally thought to be a good choice for long term maintainability.

> using ProductInventoryProjection inside OrderAggregateRoot when placing an order.

This case gets trickier, because now you are introducing a coupling between Inventory and Orders.  In a monolith, where all of the code is updated in lock step, you'll probably be fine.

More challenging is the case where Inventory code can be changed independently of Order code, because it is now easy to end up with a projector in Order that gives the "wrong" answer for some history of events.

That is, of course, less risky if your events and projections are stable - everybody using their own copy of code that won't need to change for 10 years is probably going to be painless.

In more volatile circumstances, it may be a more cost effective choice to keep the projection in Inventory, and provide *reports* that are consumed by Orders.

Comment: ```In more volatile circumstances, it may be a more cost effective choice to keep the projection in Inventory, and provide reports that are consumed by Orders.```

In this case, Inventory and Order are two different ARs, how does Inventory provide the `reports` to Orders?